# Requesting help designing the query in a Query Layer

Tags: query-layer

I am pulling data from our OMS SQL database to show our SAIDI and SAIFI numbers visually for our operations department.

I have a functioning query that can pull in the needed data, and currently I use a labeling expression to perform the math from the basic data to give the numbers I need to show.

This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Substation, Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder, COUNT(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageName) As Outages, SUM

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially) AS MemOut, SUM((Milsoft.dbo.Outage.InterruptionDuration*Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially)) 

as Time, Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total As Members FROM Milsoft.dbo.Outage, Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement WHERE 

(Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Year='2014' AND (Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.DayOfYear='181')) AND

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder=Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.ElementName) AND (Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageStartTime >= '6/1/2014' AND 

Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageStartTime <= '6/30/2014') GROUP BY  Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Substation, Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder, 

Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total
```

I can probably clean this up, I am just starting to learn this (previously used access database and its query wizard instead of building it like this).

I am trying to add the math for SAIDI, SAIFI, and CAIDI.  One of our IT guys said that as soon as the column name variable was declared I should be able to use that name in my query which lead to this:

```
SELECT Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Substation, Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder, COUNT(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageName) As Outages, SUM

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially) AS MemOut, SUM((Milsoft.dbo.Outage.InterruptionDuration*Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially)) 

as Time, Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total As Members, (Time/60/Members) AS SAIDI, (MemOut/Members) AS SAIFI, (SAIDI/SAIDI) AS CAIDI FROM 

Milsoft.dbo.Outage, Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement WHERE (Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Year='2014' AND 

(Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.DayOfYear='181')) AND(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder=Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.ElementName) AND 

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageStartTime >= '6/1/2014' AND Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageStartTime <= '6/30/2014') GROUP BY  

Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Substation, Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder, Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total
```

This throws the error:

> Time is an invalid column name

and will throw a similar error if I change the name, I tried Duration and Dur both as column names and received the same error saying it was an invalid name.

This lead to my third query:

```
SELECT Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Substation, Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder, COUNT(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageName) As Outages, SUM

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially) AS MemOut, SUM((Milsoft.dbo.Outage.InterruptionDuration*Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially)) 

as Time, Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total As Members, (SUM

(SUM((Milsoft.dbo.Outage.InterruptionDuration*Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially))/60/Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total) AS Saidi, 

(SUM(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially)/Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total) AS Saifi, 

(((Milsoft.dbo.Outage.InterruptionDuration*Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially))/60/Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total)/(SUM

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially)/Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total)) AS Caidi FROM Milsoft.dbo.Outage, 

Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement WHERE (Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Year='2014' AND (Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.DayOfYear='181')) 

AND(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder=Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.ElementName) AND (Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageStartTime >= '6/1/2014' AND 

Milsoft.dbo.Outage.OutageStartTime <= '6/30/2014') GROUP BY  Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Substation, Milsoft.dbo.Outage.Feeder, 

Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total
```

This query now works thanks to papadoo's answer, but there is still something wrong as the data is zeros giving a devide by zero error if I leave the CAIDI part in.  The strange thing is that the data for the individual columns that make up the equation come in fine.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also I seem to need to learn to edit code posts for better legibility.

Comment: You don't specify which database you are using but Time might be a reserved word. I'd try a different name, your db or ArcGIS might not like it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did try changing it to Duration, but it gave the same error only saying that Duration is an invalid column name.  The data is in a SQL database holding our OMS data I will add that to the post.

Answer (score 1):

For the third query, it looks like your parenthesis don't match up. You have one more closing than opening.

(((Milsoft.dbo.Outage.InterruptionDuration*Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially))/60/Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total)/(SUM

(Milsoft.dbo.Outage.CustomersOutInitially)/Milsoft.dbo.CustomerServedElement.Total)) AS Caidi

Comment: Thanks, that helped me see what the problem was, I had cut off a SUM command from the equation when copying and pasting.  I appreciate the help!